# Xbox doesn't allow Remote Acess in dev mode

Tags: remote-access, xbox, xbox-one, dev-mode

I just Complete a registration as a developer at Microsoft, enter Dev Mode (in registered console) in the remote access settings don't give me the IP number allowed to access Xbox remote access via browser and the address provided: https: // xboxone: 11443 / returns as: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

The Xbox Live status appears as Unknown.
The console is connected to the internet.
There is no registered test account and a Create new option is disabled.

Screen attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBrR8.jpg)

I appreciate any help

Comment: Check the network settings for the console. It looks like it just doesn't have an IP address.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue but luckily I was able to figure out the issue.

When on the Dev Home go to the settings panel.
Then click Launch Settings,
Then under the General Panel click Network Settings,
Then connect to your internet.

Once connected go back to Dev Home and it should have an address.